# Fast convert from TextBox to Text File

Tags: c#, textbox, export, text-files

I have a question about Converting from TextBox to Text File. For small files work perfect but for big file it is too slow. I read TextBox line after lines ans then save it to text file. WHat did i do here wrong? I tried with stringbuilder but the result is the same.

My code:

```
  StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(saveFileDialog2.FileName);
            //sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
            //StringBuilder sw1 = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
                //sw1.AppendLine( richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
            }

            //sw.Write(sw1.ToString());
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
```

Comment: How big is a `big file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, RichTextBox1.Text)
```

Or as mentioned in the comments:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, RichTextBox1.Lines)
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(filename, RichTextBox1.Lines)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`richTextBox1.SaveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @UniLe `richTextBox1.SaveFile("aa.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);` That's all